# Ionic 3 - debugging is not correct point in chrome

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, lazy-loading

Using ionic framework (v3). Since I am using lazy loading module in my application in browser debugging is not mapping properly.

Debugging point is going somewhere else.

App module:

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
    MyApp, 
   imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
   ]
   ...
})
```

Page component(using ionicpage) :

```
import { IonicPage } from "ionic-angular";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
```

Comment: When of the cons of lazy loading is the debugging

Comment: what you mean ? i didnt get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From

```
import { 
   FabContainer, 
   AlertController, 
   LoadingController, 
   ModalController, 
   Platform, 
   NavController, 
   Keyboard, 
   ToastController, 
   IonicPage, 
   Content 
} from "ionic-angular";
```

To

```
import { FabContainer, AlertController, LoadingController, ModalController, Platform, NavController, Keyboard, ToastController, IonicPage, Content } from "ionic-angular";
```

Got solution from ionic forums [link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/debugger-breakpoint-not-correct-in-chrome-mapping-wrong/109950/6)